# mysql error message with ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm using the Lynda.com tutorial to learn Ruby on Rails. In Chapter 6, they go through creating a mysql database and then configuring it for Rails. After we create and configure the database, the instructor tests the connection with this command from the root of our rails application

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

which created a schema.rb file in the "db" folder of the rails application.

However, for me, I got this error message when I ran the rake command

```
rake aborted!
syntax error on line 18, col 2: `  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock'

Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried to do `--trace` to check the error but it didn't do anything.

My database.yml file (where we configured the database for rails) is the same as the instructors, except his uses `mysql` and mine says `mysql2` for the adapter attribute

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: simple_cms
  password: secretpassword
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock              <<---this is line 18 as referred to in error
```

Anyways, the error message said syntax error in line 18, but my line 18 is exactly the same as the instructors...

Any ideas how I can fix this problem?

UPDATE -- this command `rake db:schema:dump --trace` gave me this output

```
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
rake aborted!
syntax error on line 18, col 2: `  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:100:in `database_configuration'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:6
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump => db:load_config
```

Comment: If you are using windows you don't need the socket parameter. Otherwise, try removing that line altogether.

Comment: You should try "rake db:schema:dump --trace" to get the backtrace. You should also try using the mysql (not mysql2) gem so that you are running with the same setup as the instructor.

Comment: @sosborn I followed the exact same installation instructions as instructor. think he had mysql2 gem as well...anyways, i did the backtrace and put it in an update in the OP. does it tell you anything?

Comment: @Ingenu I tried it without that line but then it got error messages later in file

Comment: The error above says that the yaml is not correct. Make sure you are using consistently using only spaces or only indents.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. In your database.yaml file, make sure you have a space between the key: and value. For instance,

database: simple_cms_development

password: dfdjfdfd

Make sure you have a BLANK SPACE between : and your value.

Answer (score 1):

new rails version write in routes.rb file top

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  get "demo/index"
```

don't put |map|